# Callback após moveCamera no Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2, callback

Tenho um PageView que, em um de seus Fragments, abriga um MapView com um mapa no modo "Lite". Clicando nesse mapa, é lançada uma segunda activity (`startActivityForResult`) que é composta por um mapa completo, onde é possível marcar uma determinada localização. No `onActivityResult()` do fragment, eu seto a camera para a posição marcada no mapa completo.

Sei que existe um tempo até que o mapa esteja carregado sobre a posição e o zoom especificado, então criei um spinner sobre o mapa com o atributo "Gone" em visibilidade. Quando no `onActivityResult`, troco esse atributo dinamicamente para `Visible`.

**Problema**

Em algum momento, preciso informar que o spinner deve ficar "Gone" novamente. A questão é: onde?

**O que já tentei**

Tentei implementar algumas interfaces do GoogleMaps, tais como `OnMapLoadedCallback` e `OnMapReadyCallback`. `OnMapReadyCallback` ainda é chamado, mas não quando eu quero, depois de mover a camera.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        /*Prevent null pointer when user kill the second activity without having results
          Requestcode is not being checked because there is no more than one request for "startActivityForResults"
        */
        if(data != null) {
            map.clear();
            pbStaticMap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Double latitude;
            Double longitude;

            latitude = (Double) data.getExtras().get("lat");
            longitude = (Double) data.getExtras().get("long");

            this.markPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markPosition));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(markPosition, 15));
        }
    }


map.setOnMapLoadedCallback( new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            pbStaticMap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d("MapBorba","->>> chamou onMapLoaded ( NEW CALLBACK)");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a interface `OnCameraChangeListener`, que é chamado toda vez que há um movimento no mapa. Dentro deste callback, você verifica a visibilidade do seu `Spinner` apenas para não alterar a visibilidade dele a todo momento sem necessidade:

```
seuMapa.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition pos) {
        if (seuSpinner.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE){
            seuSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }       
    }
});
```

Documentação oficial: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener.html

Comment: muito obrigado pela atenção. Já tentei fazer uso desse callback. Mas infelizmetne ele é chamado assim que se recebe a instrução de troca de posição. Ou seja, eu dou gone no spinner antes do mapa estar de fato exibindo o que deveria...